# JQuery Spinner unselectable after entering zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-spinner

I'm having a problem using the JQuery spinner widget. If I manually enter a value of 0 into the text field (not using the arrows for the spinner, just entering a value directly), then the spinner greys out and I can not select it. I have to completely restart the single board microcomputer to get it back. Any ideas what could be causing this (code below)?

```
$(function() {
        var spinner = $( "#spinner_current" ).spinner({min: 0, max: 100,
            stop: function() { dlpCurrent();} });
});

<label for="spinner_current">Illumination Power (%) </label><input id="spinner_current" style="width:30px" name="value">

$("#dlp_current_tog").button().click(function(){ dlpCurrentToggle(); });

<input type="checkbox" style="width:25px" id="dlp_current_tog" class="widgetcheckboxes"/><label for="dlp_current_tog">Turn off LEDs</label>
```

Comment: can you show `dlpCurrent` function ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The dlp_current_tog is used to turn off an LED. Where the spinner_current is used to determine the intensity of the LED when it is on. If the spinner_current has 0 entered manually, then the whole spinner become greyed out and inaccessible. Maybe the javascript functions are conflicting?